# Adding dynamic controls to TabBar,Flex 3 Air As3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I have a TabBar Control with 3 tab, i need to add controls(Button,Label) dynamically in to each tab, 
I can add the controls to the initial selected tab but when i add to next tab , i am getting 
Null exception error..
 That is when TabBar property selectedIndex="0" means i can add to 1st tab.but not in 2 and 3rd. 
when Tabbar property selectedIndex="1" means i can add to 2nd tab.but not in 1 and 3rd.

If u have any sample or link for dynamic adding controls to TabBAr control Pls reply me.

Thank in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the creationPolicy="all".

For more info: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Container.html#creationPolicy

Comment: If that is the answer please click the check mark on the left, that way others can see that the question has been answered.